# How to format dates in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to format this date: `2014-03-18T03:31:14.000Z`

Into this one: `2014-03-18 3:31 am`

I'd like split it and store it in an array.

Comment: Your input date is in GMT/UTC (that's what the `Z` means, "Zulu"). But in your output date string, do you want that in you local timezone or in GMT/UTC as well?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30927696/981049) from the question jtbandes referred to is what you are looking for, Kim.

Comment: and I just reopened the question because your question goes one step further (looking for a different formatted date string), plus putting it into an array.

Comment: What do you mean by "split it and store it in an array"? Split the date? Into what?

Comment: Hi @Rob, thanks for looking into this. Yes you were right, I would like to convert in a local timezone, specifically Brisbane Australia.

Comment: Hi @MichaelDautermann yes you were right, that's one format to solve the timestamp.

If it helps you, I'm formatting date and time from Google Calendar API. There are two different time formats:

2014-12-08T01:39:34.000Z
2015-02-12T08:45:00+10:0

I'm a bit confused on what format to use.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen, I would like to split it as in 

let splitDateTime:Array<String> = split(wholeDate) { $0 == " "}

This way I can separate the date from the time. I need to display in date UILabel and a time UILabel. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Voting to close. First 10 google result will provide lots of info.

Comment: By the way, when parsing the RFC 3339/ISO 8601 date string (the one with the `T` and `Z`), make sure to set the locale, as discussed in [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: Thanks everyone, date formatting for me is much clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do. Note that I used `stringFromDate` twice with different format strings, instead of splitting the formatted date as you wanted. Using `stringFromDate` twice is more independent from the format.

Also creation of `NSDateFormatter` is a bit expensive, it's best to reuse it.

```
let z = "2014-03-18T03:31:14.000Z"
let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let date = fmt.dateFromString(z)!

fmt.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "Australia/Brisbane")
fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let dateString = fmt.stringFromDate(date)

fmt.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
let timeString = fmt.stringFromDate(date)

print("date: \(dateString), time: \(timeString)")
```

Comment: No, do not use `YYYY`. Always use `yyyy`. Or better, use `.dateStyle` and `.timeStyle`. Also, set locale to `en_US_POSIX` in first formatter. And regarding `NSDateFormatter` being expensive, so is the changing of the `dateFormat`, so in this case the savings is modest.

Comment: Thanks Khanh and Rob!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `NSDate` object and then use a `NSDateFormatter` to create a string for the date portion and another for the time portion. Here, I saved you the trouble (make sure the `dateFormat` is correct):

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let date = formatter.dateFromString("2014-03-18T03:31:14.000Z")

formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
formatter.dateStyle = .LongStyle
formatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle
let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(date!)

formatter.dateStyle = .NoStyle
formatter.timeStyle = .LongStyle
let timeString = formatter.stringFromDate(date!)
```

Comment: If these date and time strings are for presenting in the UI, then I think this answer's use of `.dateStyle` and `.timeStyle` is the best way to go. But (a) use `.SSS` rather than `.000`; (b) use `HH` rather than `hh`; and (c) specify `locale` of `en_US_POSIX` when parsing the RFC 3339 date string.