# How to convert a string UTC date to NSDate in Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm getting UTC string dates that look like this "2015-10-17T00:00:00.000Z" and want to convert them to an NSDate in this format "October 12th 2015 11:19:12 am"

This is the route that I'm trying but I can't seem to get the right dateFormat.

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = //can't seem to get this right
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-10-17T00:00:00.000Z")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting an ISO 8601 timestamp into an NSDate: How does one deal with the UTC time offset?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185230/converting-an-iso-8601-timestamp-into-an-nsdate-how-does-one-deal-with-the-utc)

Comment: None of the answers listed there work for me for some reason

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this should work

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let localDate = formatter.date(from: date)
```

Comment: This was part of the answer, but the Date I get back isn't in the right format, but if apply a new format to this NSDate and change it to a string it works

formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d  'at'  h:mm a" 
                    var dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(localDate!)

Comment: Ok great yes I forgot to say that. Or you could make a new DataFormatter() object to retrieve date in required format.

Answer (score 3):

**This works for Swift 3.0 and latest Xcode [April 2017]**

```
let dateString = "2017-Jan-01 12:00:00.250"
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")
        let dateObj = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

        let date = dateObj
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX"
        let currentDateTime = formatter.string(from: date!)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 code**

```swift
let dateString = "2015-10-17T00:00:00.000Z"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let date = formatter.date(from: dateString)
```

You can find useful info about date formats [here](https://nsdateformatter.com)

Comment: Throws exception for me when trying to parse this date: "2020-07-16T12:13:23Z". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @DI.dev  this string has the wrong format. It doesn't match the template

Answer (score 0):

This question is a few years old but let's answer it literally.

First of all `DateFormatter` doesn't provide a format specifier for an ordinal suffix so we have to write a function

```
func ordinalSuffix(for day : String) -> String {
    switch day {
        case "1", "11", "21", "31": return "st"
        case "2", "12", "22": return "nd"
        case "3", "13", "23": return "rd"
        default: return "th"
    }
}
```

To convert the iso8601 string to date create a `DateFormatter`, set its calendar to an iso8601 calendar and convert the string to `Date`. As the time zone is specified in the string you don't need to set it explicitly

```
let dateString = "2015-10-17T00:00:00.000Z"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
guard let date = formatter.date(from: dateString) else {
    // replace that with a proper error handling
    fatalError("Could not convert date string")
}
```

To convert the date back to string you have to set the `Locale` to a fixed value, set the am/pm symbols to the lowercase versions, extract the `day` component first for the ordinal suffix calculation and then take advantage of `String(format` to insert the ordinal suffix.

```
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.amSymbol = "am"
formatter.pmSymbol = "pm"
formatter.dateFormat = "dd"
let day = formatter.string(from: date)
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd'%@' yyyy h:mm:ss a"
let output = String(format: formatter.string(from: date), ordinalSuffix(for: day))
print(output)
```